# Android studio package name issue

Tags: android

Can't seem to find the issue with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: `AboutCompany` class should inside `....myapplication` package

Answer (score 0):

Your AboutCompany is inside the root package (java) and not inside com.example.david.myapplication.

Drag and drop it to the right folder as in the package declaration of the class.

Or

Alt+Enter on the line and select "Move AboutCompany to package ...."

Another options would be removing the package (meaning default package) declaration, but this is discouraged since you cannot import the class from other packages.